# How to Remove character-counter in radio button in materializecss

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angular2-forms, materialize

[image: I want to remove this when i click on radio button then its apper]

I need to remove this span tag its come automatically when i click on radio button

Comment: support it with some code snippet

Comment: I wrote answer for you but it's better to add your code snippet in your question so it will be more useful for other people.

Answer (score 0):

I think you used `class="with-gap"` in `<input>` like this :

```
<input class="with-gap" name="group3" type="radio" checked />
```

Remove it like this :

```
<input name="group3" type="radio" checked />
```

And your problem will be solve. Read [here](https://materializecss.com/radio-buttons.html) for more info.